# Python Docstring How to write list in multiple lines in docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

I'm trying to write a list output which I expand it into multiple lines in doctest. But the actual output does not correspond with what I expect though.

Here's my code.

```py
def make_board(dimension: int, queens: list):
    """

    >>> make_board(4, [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2)])
    [[False, True, False, False],
     [False, False, False, True],
     [True, False, False, False],
     [False, False, True, False]]
    """
    assert dimension == len(queens)
    return [[(row, col) in queens for col in range(dimension)] for row in range(dimension)]
```

Here's the **Test Results**.

```
Failed example:
    make_board(4, [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2)])
Expected:
    [[False, True, False, False],
     [False, False, False, True],
     [True, False, False, False],
     [False, False, True, False]]
Got:
    [[False, True, False, False], [False, False, False, True], [True, False, False, False], [False, False, True, False]]
```

Comment: @glhr Yeah, that's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE) option. It can be enabled in different ways, for example by a directive inside the docstring:

```
def make_board(dimension: int, queens: list):
    """
    >>> make_board(4, [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2)]) # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [[False, True, False, False],
     [False, False, False, True],
     [True, False, False, False],
     [False, False, True, False]]
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want see a pretty result you can youse pprint builtin for that:

```
from pprint import pprint

def make_board(dimension: int, queens: list):
"""

>>> make_board(4, [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2)])
[[False, True, False, False],
 [False, False, False, True],
 [True, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False]]
"""
assert dimension == len(queens)

result = [[(row, col) in queens for col in range(dimension)] for row in range(dimension)]
pprint(result)

return result
```

You will see result every time you call function so I dont reccomend to do that.

```
>>>a=make_board(4, [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 2)])
[[False, True, False, False],
[False, False, False, True],
[True, False, False, False],
[False, False, True, False]]

>>>a
[[False, True, False, False], [False, False, False, True], [True, False, False, False], [False, False, True, False]]
```

Comment: It's correct. But the solution is a little verbose though because you have to import `pprint`. Thanks anyway.